# The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to run the command to run my ionic 3 Command prompt. I used cordova fcm plugin.

ionic cordova run android

ERROR:

> **The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object**

Ionic:

> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
>   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4

Cordova:

> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)    Cordova
>   Platforms     : android 7.1.4    Cordova Plugins       : no
>   whitelisted plugins (25 plugins total)

System:

> NodeJS : v10.15.1
>   (/Users/sivakumarv/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin/node)    npm    :
>   6.4.1    OS     : macOS High Sierra    Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Environment Variables:

> ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\pkhon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Along with the changes mentioned above https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330922/5698147 by Asim Hashmi
, also manually search & replace the firebase versions to

```
firebase-core:16.0.3
firebase-messaging:17.6.0
```

in

- android/build.gradle
- android/project.properties
- android/app/build.gradle

Then run `ionic cordova build android --prod`

Answer (score 24):

There is a bug in the plugin, to solve this: go to:

> plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/scripts/fcm_config_files_process.js

Now change the file like this:

```
// change
var strings = fs.readFileSync("platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml").toString();
// to
var strings = fs.readFileSync("platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml").toString();

// AND

//change
fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml", strings);

//to
fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml", strings);
```

After that, copy the `google-services.json` file to the following directories:

> - platforms/android/google-services.json
> - platforms/android/app/google-services.json

For more information, you can check this bug [here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/481)

Comment: Dude it worked, but how this file changed or I meant how this error arises in the first place

Comment: I got gradlew EACCES error when building. I did `chmod 755 gradlew` but it doesn't work now getting other errors.

Comment: `var strings = fs.readFileSync(` is on line 62 and `fs.writeFileSync` line 78