# The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object IONIC

Tags: android, ios, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic5

I am developing hybrid mobile application using Ionic, Cordova. It was working fine and build successfully in emulator and unsigned Apk File Was running fine. But after Rebuild after a month later I update ionic then Run Command

> ionic cordova build android

Getting Error:  The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

- Ionic Version: 5.0.3
- Angular Version: 7.2.16
- Cordova Version: 10.0.0

***Plugins Installed***

- cordova-clipboard 1.2.1 "Clipboard"
- cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.0.8 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
- cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
- cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-device-name 1.3.5 "Device-Name"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
- cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
- cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
- cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
- cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
- cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
- cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
- cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin -
  cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
- cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0
  "cordova-support-google-services"
- phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
- phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"

Comment: are you using `readFileSync` or `writeFileSync`

Comment: I am not using these in the code. just plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer" installed

Comment: show some of your code

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ezs-WSEm_IY3k0vehZqgEAIU3DvJiujU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can refer to the following questions [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328069/the-chunk-argument-must-be-one-of-type-string-or-buffer-received-type-object)